# How to select on strange column name in SQLite terminal?

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
sqlite> select * from questions;
data_id     data_text   data_image  parent_id   data_order  data_id:1   data_text:1
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  -----------
23          google                   5                       5           favorites
```

Hi, I'm testing query. But I want to select just the 'data_text:1' column.

I don't know how to select column.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Surround the name of the column with double-quotes

```
select "data_text:1" from questions;
```

@pst helps to explain it in a comment. I'm paraphrasing him here:

> SQLite follows SQL-92 so a double quote (which is an identifier quote) will work

Comment: .. I changed column name When I created table. Thank you.

Comment: -1 SQLite follows SQL-92. A *single quote* is for a string literal (SQLite uses a single quote for other literal types -- such blob data -- when prefixed). The code in the answer will select lots of the *value* 'data_text:1' which is not correct. A *double quote* is an identifier quote -- `select "data_text:1" from questions` would work fine. Some other SQL dialects (like that used in MySQL) do not correctly follow the SQL-92 syntax.

Comment: @Beomseok See my previous comment for how to keep the "odd" column names. However, I recommend simple column names that do not require to be quoted in SQL DQL and do not clash with SQL keywords as it make life easier.

Answer (score 0):

Surround the name of the column with double-quotes:

```
select "data_text:1" from questions;
```

SQLite follows SQL-92 syntax where double quotes are used to quote identifiers (column/table names). Single quotes are used to quote literal values like strings `'I am a string!'` or `X'ABCD'` (blob data).

Happy coding.

---

I recommend simple column names that do not require to be quoted in SQL and do not clash with reserved words as it make life easier.

Answer (score 0):

Surround the name of the column with ``

```
`data_text:1`
```

Known as a 'backtick' you usually find it above TAB and left of 1 on keyboards.
Alternatively you can get it with the combination : (alt gr + 7)

Comment: Thank you indivisible for the details :)